# SSRS - Add line at bottom of CSV export file

Tags: csv, reporting-services, export-to-csv

With SSRS, I have a report, using tablix control, that generates a list of data that I then use to export to a CSV file. Everything works just fine except the company that I have to upload this file to requires that after the last active record, there must be an "E" as the first character of the next line (to signify it has reached the end of records to import).

Example
abc,def,12,34
abd,fff,11,11
E

I've tried adding a row-outside group and putting an E in the first column.  When I render the report on screen, it shows the "E" but when I export it to CSV, the E is gone.  I've also tried adding a footer but have the same problem (shows on screen, not in CSV file).

Any ideas how to get SSRS to add a single character on a line after the data lines?

Comment: Can the line with the E be like this-> E,,, or does it HAVE to be E on it's own? If it's the former, you can just add a union all to your query make sure your sorting will put this row as the last row and you are done

Comment: hmmmm, not sure.  I'll have to check with the company we upload to and see if they stop as soon as they hit the "E" or if it has to be standalone.

Comment: Harry, turns out the company that gets the file stops processing as soon as they hit the "E" so they don't care if it's "E,,,,,,,".  Thank you very much for the sql union query suggestion.  Just did it and worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome. I'll make my comment an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the line with the E be like this-> E,,, or does it HAVE to be E on it's own? If it's the former, you can just add a union all to your query make sure your sorting will put this row as the last row and you are done